# Scrape data which loads on scrolling

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch data on this page using selenium:

https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/General-Physician-Doctors/nct-10892680

I am using BeautifulSoup, and Selenium in Python for this. But I am able to fetch only 10 records. The remaining records are loaded only when you scroll down and wait multiple times. How can this be simulated in Python or any alternative way to fetch the data?

Alternatively, I checked the Network tab and found that when new data is loaded there is a POST request to https://www.justdial.com/api/resultsPageListing?searchReferer=gen but that doesn't say anything. Usually, a page number should be there to identify which dataset will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

#### The easiest option would be to repeatedly call the same endpoint

For some reason they seem to be showing you a random selection of records each time you call the endpoint.

That might mean that you can just keep calling it, and cumulate all the results, de-duplicating as you go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a request payload with this URL https://www.justdial.com/api/resultsPageListing?searchReferer=gen, with a field "pg_no" which means page number. You can inspect that the same way using the "payload" tab. You have to send this as JSON data along with the request.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting the same results with different page_no in the curl command. Probably the timestamp needs to be updated as well